# Conditions on a ring which make the kernel of certain matrices over the power series ring trivial

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a (unital) commutative ring and let $\varphi$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over $R[[x]]$. Are there any conditions on $R$ which guarantee that $\ker(\varphi)\cap R[x]^n=0$ implies $\ker(\varphi)=0$? Certainly some conditions are necessary. By the example at the very end of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-027-03/S0002-9939-1971-0271100-6/S0002-9939-1971-0271100-6.pdf), there are $1\times 1$ matrices for which the implication fails. However, by Theorem 5 of the same paper, this issue is fixed if $R$ is assumed to be Noetherian (in fact, the theorem gives the much stronger implication $\ker(\varphi)\cap R=0\Rightarrow\ker(\varphi)=0$). This does not give an answer for the case that $\varphi$ is not $1\times 1$ though.

I am not sure whether the implication holds even in the case that $R$ is a field. I am particularly interested in the case $R=k[[x_1,\ldots,x_m]]$ for a field, $k$, but there will be no hope on that front if it does not work when $R$ is a field. If the implication does not hold under any nondegenerate conditions, will the answer change if we assume the entries of $\varphi$ are all polynomials?

Edit: As per Mohan's suggestion, in the case that $R$ is Noetherian and the entries of $\varphi$ are polynomials, the implication is true by flatness. Written more explicitly, suppose the entries of $\varphi$ are polynomials and $\ker(\varphi)\cap R[x]^n=0$. Then $\varphi:R[[x]]^n\to R[[x]]^n$ is the unique extension of the $R[x]$-linear map/matrix $\psi:R[x]^n\to R[x]^n$ whose entries are the same as $\varphi$. However, since $R$ (and hence $R[x]$) is Noetherian, $R[[x]]$ is a flat $R[x]$-module. This implies that the induced map $$\psi\otimes id_{R[[x]]}:R[x]^n\otimes_{R[x]} R[[x]]\to R[x]^n\otimes_{R[x]} R[[x]]$$ is injective. But since $R[[x]]^n\cong R[x]^n\otimes_{R[x]} R[[x]]$, we have $\psi\otimes id_{R[[x]]}=\varphi$.

I am still curious to know what happens when the entries of $\varphi$ are not polynomials, but this is sufficient for what I am currently working on.

Comment: Of course, if $\varphi$ consists of polynomials, then faithful flatness will do what you want.

Comment: @Mohan Of course! I don't know why flatness didn't cross my mind. I'll edit my question to expand on your suggestion. Thank you!